# Is it ok to use 14w charger to charge ipad

Tags: ipad

My old iPad charger broke so I had to get a new one and the one I got was a 2.8A/5V charger aka 14w charger.so is safe to use .

Comment: The charger can newer be to big (power), but it can be to small. The charging process (power) is regulated so the battery only takes what it needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers is YES you can.

The charger can newer be to big, but it can be to small (not enough juice to charge the battery)

The battery charge is controlled by the battery. It will only take as much as it can handle.